# How do I trim unwanted newlnes that remain after unwrapping tags from text?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the one liner to unwrap all `<span class='highlight'>` from elements so that I am left with only the text inside the span.

```
   $('span.highlight').contents().unwrap();
```

How do I remove unwanted new lines that are left once I remove that parent tags of the specified text contents to preserve continuity of the text?

Comment: Did you try it without `contents()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following modification to the one liner helped achieve the desired solution.

```
        $('span.highlight').each(function(){
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $(this).contents().unwrap();
            $(parent).text(parent.text().replace(/\n/g, ''));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove leading whitespace using the `^\s+` regex, and trailing whitespace using the `\s+$`. So, replace either of those matching strings in the string with nothing:

```js
var stringValue = "\r\nHi\r\n\r\nThere\r\n\r\n";
console.log(stringValue);
console.log(stringValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried the replace chained after unwrap in response to the original reply like so $('span.highlight').contents().unwrap().replace() but I am receiving a replace is not a function.